# Is there a app or software to do random photo selection on iphone?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, slideshow

I am looking for an app on iphone to do this:

1. I can select a bunch of photos into the app
2. I click a button
3. Then the app will randomly pick a photo from what I have selected and show up in the screen.

If possible the app could quickly slide through all the photos I have selected and randomly stop at one of them.

This app is very useful in a party and when people want to do a raffle gift drawing.

Is there such an app there?

Answer (score 2):

The built in slideshow would work to set the order of photos to random if you've already classified the photos into an album. Just set the delay to a while and remember to re-choose the album to re-seed the randomness if you choose to repeat the selection.

If you need to classify photos on the go, you can use the [iPhoto app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iphoto/id497786065?mt=8) to import / sort / add / remove photos from a group and then set up your random slide show for the ordering of them at random.

As a bonus, you can play music if desired while you set things up. I don't know of an app to provide your slot machine animation but perhaps someone can find just that app on the store for you.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this post was written 6 years ago but judging by the number of views it seems some people are wondering the same thing.

There's an iOS app (not sure about android) called Random Image Select that does what the original poster was looking for.